# Spring Faces Javascript

Tags: javascript, spring, jsf

I want to ask where do i put my external javascript files and how to access them in the page. I have a problem with getting the relative path for my javascript files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put them wherever you want (only not inside `WEB-INF` or `META-INF`).

You should reference them either by a relative path, i.e. no slash in the beginning:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/my.js"></script>
```

or you can use an absolute location getting it from the faces context:

```
<script src="#{facesContext.externalContext.context.contextPath}/scripts/my.js" 
     type="text/javascript"></script>
```